# OrdImage LoadFromFile exception

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, multimedia

I am trying to load an image into Oracle multimedia database. I have problem with `OrdImage.loadDataFromFile()` method which throws me a SQLException

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-22990: LOB locators cannot span transactions
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 1127
ORA-06512: at "ORDSYS.ORDSOURCE", line 801
ORA-06512: at "ORDSYS.ORDIMAGE", line 669
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

The code I use:

```
public void uploadImage(String filename) throws SQLException, IOException
    {
        ...

        // retrieve the previously created ORDImage object for future updating
        Statement stmt2 = dbModel.getConnection().createStatement();
        String selSQL = "select IMAGE from PHOTO where id="+test_id+" for update";
        OracleResultSet rset = (OracleResultSet) stmt2.executeQuery(selSQL);
        rset.next();
        OrdImage imgProxy = (OrdImage)
                rset.getORAData("IMAGE", OrdImage.getORADataFactory());
        rset.close();
        stmt2.close();

        // load the media data from a file to the ORDImage Java object
        try {
            imgProxy.loadDataFromFile("/home/anton/Documents/1.MIT_zima/UPA/upa-project/app/Kataster/car42.gif");
        }
       catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
       }
        // set the properties of the Oracle Mm object from the Java object
        imgProxy.setProperties();

        ...
    }
```

Exception is thrown by line:

```
imgProxy.loadDataFromFile("/home/anton/Documents/1.MIT_zima/UPA/upa-project/app/Kataster/car42.gif");
```

Comment: Please post a [mre]. You likely didn't disable auto-commit mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this `setAutoCommit(false)`

> Issue the setAutoCommit(false) command. Then, explicitly commit the
>
> transaction after all of the Blob chunks have been written to the row
>   and
>
> the stream.close() method has been executed.
>
> If using the Oracle 10g JDBC driver (or greater version), a second
>   solution
>
> consists of using the standard JDBC api (setBinaryStream method
>
> of java.sql.PreparedStatement interface). And in this case, AutoCommit
>   can
>
> be set to true;